# What does $\mathbb Z_+$ mean?

Tags: definition

I am not so sure whether the meaning of $$\mathbb Z_+$$ is very clear. How many different definitions are there? Does the definition that is used depend on whether the writer is English or German?

In French maths, this notation doesn't exist.

Comment: I think that we use the notations : $\mathbb{Z}=\{\ldots,-2,-1,0,1,2,\ldots\}$, $\mathbb{Z}_+=\{0,1,2,\ldots\}$ and  $\mathbb{N}=\{1,2,\ldots\}$

Comment: It depends on the context. A guess is that it means the additive group of $\Bbb Z$, i.e. $\Bbb Z$ when one considers the addition only.

Comment: Without any doubt $\mathbb N$ includes $0$.

Comment: @DamienL, alas there is doubt.

Comment: @DamienL Not true. I define $\mathbb{N} = \varnothing$, then $0\not\in\mathbb{N}$. My point is that you can't argue in general without stating your definition. BTW, there are people who define $\mathbb{N} = \{1,2,\cdots\}$

Comment: hoho… Thank you for pointing that out vadim !

Comment: @vadim123: In fact $0\in\Bbb N$ is a counterexample to the principle of the excluded middle: it is a proposition that contains no variables, yet it is neither true nor false ;-(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Many people would interpret this to mean $\{1,2,3,\ldots\}$, although some might argue for $\{0,1,2,3,\ldots\}$.  Absent any other context I don't think any other interpretations are likely.

Sadly, many authors use notations without defining them, because they are "standard" in their little corner of mathematics.

Comment: That would more likely be $\Bbb Z_{>0}$ or $\Bbb Z_{\geq0}$, but everything is possible!

Comment: Some people still uses : $\mathbb{R}_+=[0,\infty)$ for $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$.

Comment: Which causes my stupefaction about how people could "resolve" the ambiguity of the symbol $\Bbb N$ with another one that raises _exactly_ the same problem!

Answer (score 5):

Symbol "$+$" means "positive", so $\mathbb{Z}_+$ shoud properly be understood as $\{1,2,3,\ldots\}$. It's less confusing that undefined $\mathbb{N}$ in some paper, where we don't know if it includes $0$.

Comment: It's interesting because in french "positif" means non-negative. So it needs context probably.

Comment: Actually $+$ means addition, not positive. If $n<0$ then $+n$ is (also) negative while $-n$ is positive. Therefore $\Bbb Z_+$ is an abomination that only makes the embassement of not being able to assign a uinque truth value to $0\in\Bbb N$ even worse; it should have been $\Bbb Z_{>0}$ (or even better $\Bbb N_{>0}$), which would never have raised the current question.

Comment: It depends on context. For example, when we are talking about electric fileds, positive electric charge is labaled by "$+$", and negative by "$-$" (not by $">0"$ nor $"<0"$). Thus I don't see anything wrong in labeling positive numbers by "$+$". This example could be used also as a respond to @Thibaut Dumont: I think that putting "$0$" as a positive number (like in french notation) is not too good ($0$ is not positive nor negative; it's neutral).

Answer (score 1):

For the  French  notation $\mathbb N=\{0,1,2,3,\ldots\}$ and $\mathbb N^*=\{1,2,3,\ldots\}$ and and the notation $\mathbb Z_+$  is not used in general but it means $\mathbb N$.

Comment: In the U.S. it is far from standard but common is $\mathbb{N}=\{1,2,3,\ldots\}$ and $\mathbb{N}_0=\{0,1,2,\ldots\}$.